# MVC: Relationship between controller and model

Tags: model-view-controller, model, view, controller

I'm slightly confused about the controller-model relationship in MVC.

Should a controller be able to access *any* model in the system or should it have a 1:1 relationship with a specific model? Both options seem to present problems:

If the relationship is 1:1 obviously if something elsewhere needs to be updated it can't for example updating a window title from outside the window triad. So should models have access to other models (And how do they find them?)

If it's not 1:1 and the controller can access any model, how are these usually accessed (service locator?) and what if there needs to be more than one instance of a specific model.

I'm a bit confused! Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are of course many ways to program, but if you use the one to many then you could use the Repository pattern. Check out the NerdDinner tutorial for more info on that pattern.
http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

Answer (score 3):

For basic CRUD abilities I think a 1:1 relationship works, but it is by no means a rule that every controller should have a corresponding model.  That being said, I obviously don't think it's an issue to access multiple models within a controllers.

The only thing that has a 1:1 relationship in my MVC applications is models and tables.

Answer (score 1):

The MVC paradigm is based on one main rule, namely **separation of concerns**. Making a controller 1:1 dependent via some kind of relationship with a model is not separating those concerns, but making them more unified. A controller called "users" *should* only talk to a model called *users*, but why go and make that a explicit relationship?

Models should almost always exist in an exclusive static context, so they are easily accessed within controllers and other models.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I don't access the model direct from the controller. I usually add another layer between the model and the controllers.
For example:
Controller Layer->Service Layer->Model Layer

For every Model class, I build a Service class to access it and the Controllers can access every Services in the application. 
I think it's a good way to do things.
If you need some examples, please ask. :)